# Get route result in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, routes, request, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on an ASP.NET Coe Web API project.

I have a `post` method (route) and I need it to call another `get` method:

```
[HttpGet(Name = "Profile")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ProfileResponseDto>> GetProfile(string username)
```

If I call :

```
return RedirectToRoute("Profile", new { username = profile.UserName });
```

I will end up with `Get` resource.

But what I want is to take the result of that `Get` method and continue in my post method.

In Python its something like

```
amount = requests.get("http://"+catalogIpAddress+":"+port+"/count/" + str(id))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpResponse.RedirectToRoute Method Redirects a request to a new URL by using route parameter values, a route name, or both this means that you cannot continue with the last URL

[HttpResponse.RedirectToRoute Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirecttoroute?view=netframework-4.8)

but you can return value from another action result like

```
var result = await controller.GetTodosAsync();
```

so you can use like this :

```
        [HttpGet(Name = "Profile")]
        public async Task<string> GetProfile(string username)
        {
           return await Task.Run(()=> "hello") ;
        }

        [HttpPost(Name = "Profile")]
        public async Task<string> PostProfile(string username)
        {
            string result = await this.GetProfile(username);

            result = result + " from post";
            return await Task.Run(() => result);
        }
```